# Close dialog fragment using button in java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm experimenting making a selection option via dialog fragment. The options are, manual input, and preset input, the preset being represented by two buttons. The current issue i'm facing, is that when a press the button, i want the dialog to close and set the information to the target TextView, i've been unable to find a solution.

Currently with buttonfps2397 i'm populating the EditText within the dialog and pressing ok to send it to the target TextView, one click to much for me.

```
public class FpsDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment{
private EditText editTextFpsEntry;
private FpsDialogListener listener;
private Button buttonfps2397;
private Button buttonfps50;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fps_dialog, null);

    builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle("Login")
            .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    String fpsinfo = editTextFpsEntry.getText().toString();
                    listener.applyText(fpsinfo);

                }
            });


    editTextFpsEntry = view.findViewById(R.id.fpsEntry);
    buttonfps2397 = view.findViewById(R.id.fps2397);
    buttonfps50 = view.findViewById(R.id.fps50);

    buttonfps2397.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String setFps2397 = "23,97";
            editTextFpsEntry.setText(setFps2397);



        }
    });
    buttonfps50.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String setFps50 = "50";
            listener.applyText(setFps50);
        }
    });


    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    try {
        listener = (FpsDialogListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()+
                "must implement Lens Dialog Listener");
    }

}


public interface FpsDialogListener{
    void applyText(String fpsinfo);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instances of `DialogFragment` have a `dismiss()` method. You can call this from your button click listeners in order to close the dialog.

```
buttonfps2397.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String setFps2397 = "23,97";
        editTextFpsEntry.setText(setFps2397);
        dismiss(); // <---- closes the dialog
    }
});
```

Comment: than kyou, it actually works with the buttonfps50 because that one is the one with the method populating the TextView.